# Is there a PHPDoc standard to describe function attributes passed by reference?

Tags: php, phpdoc

I have a function which uses an attribute passed as reference:

```php
public function doSomething(&$argumentPassedByReference)
{
    // ...
}
```

I maintain the PHPDoc of my project, so I described my function like this:

```php
/**
 * Do something very useful with the thing passed in parameters
 *
 * @param Type $argumentPassedByReference Thing that will be edited
 */
public function doSomething(&$argumentPassedByReference)
```

But I'm not really satisfied because it doesn't show that `$argumentPassedByReference` is passed by reference. Is there a standard in PHPDoc to describe this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the ampersand as in the function definition:

```
 /**
 * Do something very useful with the thing passed in parameters
 *
 * @param Type &$argumentPassedByReference Thing that will be edited
 */
```

Comment: Ah so I was doing this right? PHPStan claims this is wrong: PHPDoc tag @param has invalid value (array &$config Configuration (this will be modified for type strictness and trimming)): Unexpected token "&", expected variable at offset 61

Comment: MediaWiki has a [custom phpcs sniff](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-tools-codesniffer/blob/5096ad00ac76e5f912c7f029e082e3a288388bb4/MediaWiki/Sniffs/Commenting/FunctionCommentSniff.php) for enforcing this style. Personally I find it annoying and useless - these days IDEs and code generators are clever enough to identify the parameter as a reference without any explicit markup. And technically it violates PSR-19, although of course PSR-19 is only a draft (and does not seem to be going anywhere).

Answer (score 0):

Psalm has [@param-out](https://psalm.dev/docs/annotating_code/supported_annotations/#param-out-psalm-param-out) for marking the output type - not quite the same thing but might be useful.